# Parse a JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json

I would like to know how I can access the data from the below JSON String.

```
{
    "posters": {
            "thumbnail": "http://google.com/images/11420914_ori.jpg",
            "profile": "http://google.com/images/11420914_ori.jpg"
    }
}
```

I want this to be done in Java Lists (NOT by using JSON Parsers)

**Expected output:**

thumbnail: "http://google.com/images/11420914_ori.jpg"
profile: "http://google.com/images/11420914_ori.jpg"

Comment: Is this JSON even correct?

Comment: @bmarkham yes because I am getting that in response

Comment: It's not. Keys should be quoted in JSON.

Comment: Doesn't JSON need to start with `[` or `{` ? Meaning, why is `posters` even there?

Comment: @bmarkham Yeah, that too :)

Comment: @Vamsi No idea what you even mean when you say: _I want this to be done in Java Lists (NOT by using JSON Parsers)_

Comment: @bmarkham, Robby Cornelissen I have edited the and kept the actual JSON String.
Robby Cornelissen, I need the implementation of it in List

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. I don't understand the problem. Parse the JSON however you see fit, and store it however you want in whatever type of Java object you want.

Comment: Is your expected outcome to but the values in a list?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, Yes I changed the URL by removing the necessary content that I can't share. 
But I also posted the desired output that I want.

Comment: @bmarkham, if I get them in a list then I can iterate and show the result

Comment: So how can we help if we get 404's?

Comment: So then use JSON parsers and put them in a list. You can't PARSE json without json PARSERS

Answer (score 0):

You need a Json Mapper, I recommend you to read this : [Jackson in 5 minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)